# How can I change the factors to numeric variables or otherwise deal with this error I'm getting in my linear regression

Tags: r

Trying to run a linear regression model with this dataset, mro.csv, but when I run lm() it gives the error message:

```
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Not sure what parts of the dataset are factors and not numeric, all the data is numbers except column names.Also unsure what the '-' not meaningful for factors part is about because there are no -'s in the dataset either.

Not sure how to share the dataset, but here's the csv in a google sheet: [mro.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJKMKDscWbicdu3P_P3a12Fe3XU57Z77L36_MQZRU9k/edit#gid=599336034)

```
> raw <- read.csv("/Users/cpt.jack/Downloads/mro.csv",header<-F,sep<-",") 
> colnames(raw)<- c("inlf","hours","kidslt6","kidsge6","age", "educ",  "wage", "repwage",             "hushrs", "husage", "huseduc","huswage",  "faminc",  "mtr",  "motheduc",  "fatheduc",    "unem","city", "exper",  "nwifeinc",  "lwage",  "expersq")  
> 
> 
> dim(raw)
[1] 753  22
> 
> set.seed(88)
> raw  <- raw[sample(nrow(raw)),]
> 
> 
> raw1<-raw[raw$inlf==1,]
> dim(raw)
[1] 753  22
> dim(raw1)
[1] 428  22
> 
> 
> reg1 <- lm(wage~ hours + kidslt6 + kidsge6 + age + educ + hushrs + husage + huseduc + huswage
+mtr+motheduc+fatheduc+unem
+exper+nwifeinc, data=raw1)

Warning messages:

1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored

2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
> reg1 <- lm(wage~ hours,data=raw1)
```

Comment: The message is saying the the response, `wage`, is a factor. Can you share your data (`dput(raw)`)?

Comment: Some other things: For arguments you should use `=` rather than `<-` (e.g. `header = FALSE`). Also, you should avoid the variable name `raw` as this is the name of a base function.

Comment: not sure how I'm supposed to share data @Paul but I just added a link to the dataset

Answer (score 0):

`wage` and `lwage` are being read as `factor`s because they contain the value `"."` which can't be parsed as numeric. This value can be handled manually.

```
df <- read.csv(
  "~/Downloads/mro.csv",
  header = FALSE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  col.names = c(
    "inlf", "hours", "kidslt6", "kidsge6", "age", "educ",  "wage",
    "repwage", "hushrs", "husage", "huseduc", "huswage",  "faminc",
    "mtr",  "motheduc",  "fatheduc", "unem", "city", "exper",
    "nwifeinc", "lwage", "expersq"
  )
)

df$wage <- as.numeric(ifelse(df$wage == ".", 0, df$wage))
df$lwage <- as.numeric(ifelse(df$lwage == ".", 0, df$lwage))
```

Now the `lm` should run without issues.

```
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]
df1 <- df[df$inlf == 1, ]

reg1 <- lm(
  wage ~ hours + kidslt6 + kidsge6 + age + educ + hushrs + husage + huseduc +
         huswage + mtr + motheduc + fatheduc + unem + exper + nwifeinc,
  data = df1
)
```